# I have build a logo but there are two on my site?

Tags: html, css, image

my problem is that there is 2 divs stacking on each other I am not sure why. when I put 5 div boxes this happens.

I only want to have to all of the divs on one row but I am not sure why it's not working

```css
.Box {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 18%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 10.5px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid black 5px;
  float: left;
  margin: 100px 40px;
}

.Logo1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  margin: 25px;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100); /*url(Pictures/animal-2028258.png); original img path*/
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="Box">
    <div class="Logo1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With current code posted here, I couldn't be able to reproduce the issue you mentioned

Comment: Use display:flex on the wrapper and remove some of the margins

Comment: The question was edited by another person that is not the OP and it changed its meaning entirely... not sure how the person that edited knows what OP really wants, because original question largely different from what has been edited now

Answer (score 1):

It is important that if you are using percentage then all things should flexible and use percent value like margin, paddings, etc..

I have updated all box sizes and margins with the percentage in CSS it works correctly.

Hope this helps!

```css
.Box {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 18%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid black 5px;
  float: left;
  margin: 100px 40px;
}

.Logo1 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  margin: 10%;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100); /*url(Pictures/animal-2028258.png); original img path*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="Box">
    <div class="Logo1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
  <div class="Box"></div>
</div>
```